# jquery ui selectable - nothing happens

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I don't know if I'm using the .selectable() API of jQuery UI entirely wrong. The expected result of this script is to simply get some alerts during the selecting of the black box (div):

http://jsfiddle.net/jMDVm/32/

I've had nothing but trouble with creating my own selectables() so I feel I must have missed something very basic about that particular function.

Comment: Also note that you can set 'filter' to prevent certain items to selectable. By default it is '*'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in the documentation, you call `.selectable()` on an element, and then the elements *inside* that become selectable. You want to add some things inside of your `#selectable` div.

http://jsfiddle.net/jMDVm/40/

Comment: Ah, that's what I have missed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [documentation example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/) - you need to call `.selectable()` on your `#wrapper` to affect all of its child nodes.

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86245/) of your markup/code.

```
$("#wrapper").selectable({
        selected: function(event, ui) {
            alert("Selected");
        },
        selecting: function(event, ui) {
            alert("Selecting");
        }
});

<div id="wrapper" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;">
            <div id="selectable"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks. Clint Tseng answered earlier with pretty much the same information so I'm marking his answer. Hope you don't mind.